# Use of Gsub in editing a column

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am trying to replace text data in a column of the form: `Defoe 12, 69, Johnson 40` with `Defoe 12, Defoe 69, Johnson 40` with -

```
latest$AGS24 <-gsub(pattern="(.*)([[:space:]])([[:digit:]]),([[:space:]])([[:digit:]]),([[:space:]])",replacement="\\1\\3\\1\\5",latest$AGS23)
```

but this is not doing the job. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You regex doesn't work because `[[:digit:]]` indicates a single digit but not multiple ones.

You can use this approach:

```
test <- "Defoe 12, 69, Johnson 40"

gsub("\\b(\\w+\\s)(\\d+,\\s)(?=\\d)", "\\1\\2\\1", test, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "Defoe 12, Defoe 69, Johnson 40"
```